# Assets execution step failing in codepipeline - CDK (Java)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I'm a newbie here and I need any help possible with CDK codepipeline.
I'm trying to deploy a module using the pipeline and for some reason its stuck at the 'Assets' execution step.

> Error: Cannot read asset manifest at 'assembly-xxxPipelinexxxStack-Deploy/xxxPipelinexxxStackDeployxxxPipelinexxxStackF5F6A16A.assets.json': ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'assembly-xxxPipelinexxxStack-Deploy/xxxPipelinexxxStackDeployxxxPipelinexxxStackF5F6A16A.assets.json'

I have checked the **cdk.out** and it does contain the required file at location *assembly-xxxPipelinexxxStack-Deploy/xxxPipelinexxxStackDeployxxxPipelinexxxStackF5F6A16A.assets.json*

The auto-created buildspec file is as below:

```
{
  "version": "0.2",
  "phases": {
    "install": {
      "commands": [
        "npm install -g cdk-assets"
      ]
    },
    "build": {
      "commands": [
        "cdk-assets --path \"assembly-xxxPipelinexxxStack-Deploy/xxxPipelinexxxStackDeployxxxPipelinexxxStackF5F6A16A.assets.json\" --verbose publish \"38341e9ef6b01cd2c7cc3b47cd0d2da98933b1121302bf0b03603950b8ff0bd4:current_account-current_region\""
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The pipeline stages are:

- **Source** - Success
- **Build** - Success

  - **Synth** - Success
- **Asset**

  - **FileAsset1** - Failed

Appreciate your time and reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify this, but I'm assuming you're using [CDK pipelines](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-eventsourcemapping.html) (not [`aws-cdk-lib.aws_codepipeline`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codepipeline-readme.html)).

This is a quirk of CDK pipelines - the buildspec has to change to reflect each change in the asset. What this means in practice is that when you're using assets, you have to enable [self-mutation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines.CodePipeline.html#selfmutation) for the pipeline, which you disabled, it seems.

Comment: Thanks a lot @gshpychka for your answer, yes, I am using CDK pipeline `awscdk.pipelines.CodePipeline;`

However, I had to disable the self mutation because it was failing in the first place, the error I'm getting for self-mutation is:
`No stacks match the name(s) xxxPipelinexxxStack`
More errors in next comment

Comment: `Error: No stacks match the name(s) xxxPipelinexxxStack
    at CdkToolkit.validateStacksSelected (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/cdk-toolkit.ts:545:13)
    at CdkToolkit.selectStacksForDeploy (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/cdk-toolkit.ts:492:10)
    at CdkToolkit.deploy (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/cdk-toolkit.ts:120:20)
    at initCommandLine (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/bin/cdk.ts:267:9)`

_Command did not exit successfully cdk -a . deploy xxxPipelinexxxStack --require-approval=never --verbose exit status 1_

Comment: Self-mutation has to be enabled when using assets. As for your issue, I would post it as a separate question, because it is unrelated to the asset issue in the question. Although I would try to do a manual `cdk deploy` of the stack first (with enabled self-mutation).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response - gshpychka. I've tried manual cdk deploy, but still it fails. I've posted a different question as per your advice.

Comment: I assume assets are automatically created when a stage is added for a `pipelines.CodePipeline` ? Judging by the docs for the [selfMutation?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines.CodePipeline.html#selfmutation) property. 
@gshpychka Any ideas on iterating without having to push every change ?

Edit: I guess you could just deploy the stack that the Pipeline stage is deploying, on it's own. Then test the entire pipeline flow when you end up pushing the changes to SC.